# Kotlin - How to wait for async coroutine to complete the job

Tags: android, kotlin, async-await, kotlin-coroutines

I have two function. first function is used to check ID is available or not in database then it will return the Boolean value based on result. Second function is depended on first function response if Id is exists in DB then show pop message else insert data into DB.

Here is my problem:

if ID exist in DB still initially checkIfIDExistsInDatabase() return false then it will go inside the else condition and meanwhile it will complete the job for async coroutine so how can I tell to coroutine to wait for complete the job then go in else condition?

-> if ID exist in DB :
{
Actual result : showing pop-up message as well as inserting the ID in DB also

Expected result : should show only pop-up message
}

-> if ID not exist in DB :
{
its working as expected
}

```
private fun checkIfIDExistsInDatabase(): Boolean {
        var isIDExists = false
        GlobalScope.launch {
            val isIDAvailable = GlobalScope.async { withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { bbdViewModel.isIDExists(id) } }
            if (isIDAvailable.await()) {
                Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
                    isIDExists = true
                    Dialog.getInstance(activity)
                            .setMessage(R.string.id_already_exists_in_db)
                            .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null)
                            .show()
                }
            }
        }
        return isIDExists
    }


private fun findId() {
            if (checkIfIDExistsInDatabase) {
                //want to show pop that ID is already inserted into DB
            } else {
                //want to insert ID in DB
            }
        }
```

Note : If I use runBlocking instead of GlobalScope.async/launch then its working fine but it is not a recommended way to use runBlocking.

I have gone through several SO answer (many answers related to use runBlobking())but didnt get solution for my query. Please give me some suggestion. What can I do ?

Comment: I think you can use `join()` to wait for your coroutine to end

Comment: @BilalNaeem already tried not working as expected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `GlobalScope.launch`, it builds a coroutine and schedules it for execution and after executing this statement underlying thread moves to next statement. lets see in what order `checkIfIDExistsInDatabase` statements are executed

```
private fun checkIfIDExistsInDatabase(): Boolean {
    var isIDExists = false    // Executed first
    GlobalScope.launch {      // Executed second

    // Any code inside launch is Executed fourth

    }
    return isIDExists        // Executed third
}
```

This means `checkIfIDExistsInDatabase` will always return `false`, because coroutine have not started executing.

One solution to your problem is to use `suspend` functions, If you are using `Room` DB then you can mark your `dao` functions with `suspend` modifier. this would allow you to write code in a better way, without the need of all coroutine job status management.

This can be done by following below steps

1. Mark isIDExists function with `suspend` modifier
2. Now update your activity with following changes

```
// Declare LiveData object
private val showPopUp: MutableLiveData<Boolean> = MutableLiveData()

// Launch the coroutine using lifecycleScope, don't use GlobalScope
private fun checkIfIDExistsInDatabase() = lifecycleScope.launch {
    if(bbdViewModel.isIDExists(id)){
        showPopUp.postValue(true)
    }
    else{
        // Insert the id in DB
    }
}


// Observe the LiveData object in Activity onCreate to show the popup
showPopUp.observe(this, Observer{
    // Show the popup dialog here
})
```

Comment: where is `checkIfIDExistsInDatabase` defined, in `Activity` or `Fragment`?

Comment: Its a nested subpage and in this subpage I have the reference of activity.

Comment: `lifecycleScope` property is defined for `Activity`, so you can access it using `Activity` reference.

Comment: ok fine got it...let me try your suggested answer

Comment: shall I use GlobalScope.lauch{checkIfIDExistsInDatabase()} from the button click for remove the error of `Suspend function 'checkIfIDExistsInDatabase' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function`

Comment: sorry my mistake, you need to remove the `suspend` modifier from `checkIfIDExistsInDatabase`, will update the answer

Comment: Its ok....Thanks a lot@mightyWOZ your answer resolved my issue.

Comment: one problem is there I have defined observer in onCreateView() so after inserting data in DB whenever I come to the page to it show popup dialog because its observe the data is in DB but it popup dialog should only when condition it true not when we come to the page

Comment: just add an if condition inside observer as `showPopUp.observe(this, Observer{
    if(it) { // Show the popup dialog only when its value is true }
})`

Comment: yes I have added the condition still its showing. I think so somewhere I have to set the value bbdCarViewModel.isShowDialog.postValue(false ) also right ?